# Testing http Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I will need writed my http `GET` method downloand image.
Example Url : `http://example/file/?filepath=/Rbfk/LZTrq/PKMH3ks.jpg`

Testing by Laravel from box.

```
$responseMedia = $this->get("file/?filepath=/Rbfk/LZTrq/PKMH3ks.jpg");
```

Am I doing the right thing, and are there any alternative testing options.

My controller:

```
public function getMediaFile(Request $request)
    {

        $bucket = \DB::getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();

        $filePath = $request->filepath;
        /** @var Bucket $bucket */

        $doc = $bucket->findOne(['filename' => $filePath]);

        if ($doc instanceof BSONDocument) {
            $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

            header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=' . $doc->filename);

            header('Content-type: image/png');

            return $bucket->downloadToStream($doc->_id, $handle);
        } else {
            return response()->make('', 404);
        }
    }
```

Response Error : `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /code/src/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:110)`

Comment: Your error tells you the problem, `cannot modify header` and you clearly have two `header()` calls.